# How to remove empty space in StackLayout - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a StackLayout with one button and two labels.

I want to remove the empty space between StackLayout and the button.

I using Spacing = "0" but this isn't work for me.

```
 <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                 HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                 Spacing="0">
          <Button Text="ОФИЦИАЛЕН WEB САЙТ"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Clicked="OnButtonClickedWeb"
                                x:Name="webButton"
                                WidthRequest="150"
                                HeightRequest="30"
                                FontSize="10"/>
         <Label Text="Създаден от Благовест Пижев, тел: +359 899 91 66 79, е-mail: pizhevsoft@gmail.com" 
              HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
              VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
              HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
              VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
              FontAttributes="Bold"
              FontSize="10"
              TextColor="White"/>
       <Label Text="Финансирано по програма ННП 'Млади учени, докторанти и постдокторанти.' от МОН. НИМХ - Филиал Пловдив." 
              HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
              VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
              HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
              VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
              FontAttributes="Bold"
              FontSize="10"
              TextColor="White"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

When I use HeighRequest the lyrics of the labels are not visible and go down.

[image: Empty Space]

Comment: are you sure the problem isn't between the StackLayout and whatever element is before it?

Comment: When I enter HeightRequest = "200" the stacklayout is shrinking, I can't reduce height under 90.. Why ?

Comment: I have no idea what that has to do with the question I asked you.  I'd suggest you assign BG colors to all of the elements in your UI so you can visualize where the spacing actually is.

Answer (score 1):

you can add Padding Property
Padding="0"

you can also(if you want) add Margin="0,-10,0,0"